# Run genhtml in WSL

Tags: flutter, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lcov

I've been trying to use WSL to generate html reports for the code coverage of my flutter project, but this happens when I run `genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html`:

```
Reading data file coverage/lcov.info
Resolved relative source file path "lib\blocs\bloc1\bloc1.dart" with CWD to "/mnt/c/Users/User/flutter_project/lib\blocs\bloc1\bloc1.dart".
Found 284 entries.
Found common filename prefix "/mnt/c/Users/User/flutter_project"
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
Processing file flutter_project/lib\otherDir\other_file.dart
genhtml: ERROR: cannot read /mnt/c/Users/User/flutter_project/lib\otherDir\other_file.dart
```

I can understand that this has possibly to do with the paths, but I'm not sure on how to fix it. Any tips?

Comment: Try to use the user home folder (`~`) in WSL instead of C drive (`/mnt/c`).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem when attempting to use lcov through WSL, and I have figured out the issue.

The lcov file generated by `flutter test --coverage` on Windows has back slashes `\` for paths instead of forward slashes `/`.

Simply replacing all back slashes in your `lcov.info` file with forward slashes before running `genhtml`, should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be useful in that environment.

I had the same problem, and to solve it I created this script. I hope this helps you!

https://github.com/jorgesarabia/flutter_coverage

Please let me know if this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this!!

Instead of cd'ing into **coverage/** then running **genhtml lcov.info -o anything**

Just run the whole command from the root of project, So the new command will look something like this:-

**genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o anything**

P.S. I was trying to run a coverage file generated by Flutter test.